# IntelliJ fails running o startup

Tags: intellij-idea

I am having issues with IntelliJ. I have been able to use it with no issues in the past but have recently been unable to use due to it freezing because of the following errors on startup.

```
me@mymachine:~/idea-IU-139.1117.1$ ./bin/idea.sh 
Exception in thread "AWT-XAWT" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-XAWT"

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0 14.0.3#IU-139.1117.1, eap:false"
Exception in thread "Performance watcher" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from theUncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Performance watcher"
```

Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-0"

I have tried increasing my vmoptions but it hasn't worked. I even tried reinstalling.

machine: ubuntu, 64 bit

Comment: I have 3 questions. Do you use OpenJDK or Oracle JDK? What is its version? Have any previous IntelliJ IDEA start up succesful?

Answer (score 1):

Because have this line: `Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`, I guess your problem about memory heap size.
You should try changing Java heap size.

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

add this line:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS = -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m
```

with 1024 MB is memory heap size, You can change this value.

Reference: [Setting environment variables permanently](https://askubuntu.com/a/280876/299516) , [JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html).